# htaccess image, css problem

Tags: image, .htaccess

I have a question.
When i use this htaccess script and put this in the directorty "test"

The dir structory

base: test

images: test/images css:

test/css

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.*) index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

When I use this url "http://xxxxxxx/test/producten/" everything works fine, but when I use this url "http://xxxxxxx/test/producten/subpage" He doesn't find the images

Answer (score 0):

Should this section have a forward slash?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```